# WCF Percall mode and threadstatic variables

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

We have multiple WCF services all working with InstanceContextMode=PerCall and all WCF service instances are generated by employing Unity (IOC) and implementing IInstanceProvider.

A correlation identifier is used to audit all method calls and database processes with the same identifier.

In order to achieve this, an endpoint behavior is created by implementing IDispatchBehavior and in AfterReceiveRequest method, a guid is generated and assigned to a ThreadStatic (`CommonData`) property. This property can be access in all layers of the application. The following code block shows the population of CommonData, and the CommonData class;

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            CommonData.ClearDictionary();
            //the lines between are deleted as they are not relevant to the question

            CommonData.Current.Add(MessageHeaderCodes.CorrelationId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());    
            return null;
        }
```

and commondata class:

```
public class CommonData
    {            
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static Dictionary<string, string> headerData;    

        public static Dictionary<string, string> Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (headerData == null)
                {
                    headerData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                }
                return headerData;
            }            
        }

        private CommonData()
        {

        }

        public static string GetHeader(string header)
        {
            string headerValue = string.Empty;
            KeyValuePair<string, string> headerKeyValuePair = CommonData.Current.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == header);
            headerValue = headerKeyValuePair.Value;
            return headerValue;
        }

        public static void ClearDictionary()
        {
            Current.Clear();
        }
    }
```

The problem here is the following;
In some of the services, developers reported that the correlation identifier returns null. Since the problem is intermittant it is not possible to have a full stack trace at the moment. Also, they stated that reseting IIS resolves this problem temporarily.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: how exactly do you retrieve the identifier(i guess by the GetHeader method)?

Comment: I do not get the identifier from client, I just create a new identifier for each call in the AfterReceiveRequest method; CommonData.Current.Add(MessageHeaderCodes.CorrelationId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

Comment: yes but you try to retrieve it later somehow right? how? if not - then what is null exactly?

Comment: that is the exact question in fact:) I create a guid in order to correlate all running methods with database changes. For instance, if a service method is called, a log is generated with the id generated; the same id is also employed in all database changes. Thus it is possible to map service calls to method calls and database changes.

Comment: well, maybe I understand, but then why do you need a dictionary. just one string value(per thread) will be sufficient, no?

Comment: Each message header has some entries and this entries are also need to be stored. that is why it is a dictionary, but I removed that code sections as they do not seem to be related.

Comment: Only a comment - actually more a question.  Why not use SessionID?

Comment: @Blam good point, services work in percall mode; is it possible to use SessionID in this mode?

Comment: Yes even with PerCall SessionID is durable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005211/wcf-manage-session-state-information

Comment: @Blam I have read the thread, no need to create a new identifier. On the otherhand, I still need to persist identifier somewhere as I need to access it in all layers; and layers are decoupled from each other. I think I will still have the problem anyway. But I will give a try.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by layer.  Could you provide an example of a layer that does not have access to OperationContext.Current.SessionId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blam suggested, I have employed OperationContext.Current by writing an Extension to store custom objects. Below is the extension:

```
public class OperationContextExtension : IExtension<OperationContext>
{
    public void Attach(OperationContext owner)
    {
        this.Current = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void Detach(OperationContext owner)
    {
        this.Current = null;
    }

    public Dictionary<string,string> Current { get; set; }
}
```

On the otherhand, I have to add System.ServiceModel reference to the domain objects. Although it does not seem to be a proper way as domain objects can access to the service layer, it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, and would have been a comment, except I wanted to have some code...

I am confused by your GetHeader method. Why are you doing a Linq `.FirstOrDefault()` on the dictionary, instead of just:

```
public static string GetHeader(string header)
{
    if(CommonData.Current.ContainsKey(header))
        return CommonData.Current[header];
    return null;
}
```

---

Aside from that, I don't actually see anything wrong with your code. I am curious as to where the developers are getting the null identifier. They would of course have to make sure they are on the same thread that the dispatcher was called on. If any async process, or ThreadPool was used anywhere to run something on another thread, then the [ThreadStatic] would not exist.

I had an issue once where I (very stupidly) referenced my `[ThreadStatic]` variable from a method that was called by a finalizer, which is run on the GC thread, so my thread static was always null. oops :)

Comment: you are right on firstordefault comment; I will update since it may result in an exception if headerKeyValuePair is null. The developers are getting null value in business related code. maybe it is better to give more detail about structure, but I thought that I was just missing something very simple. I will try to update the question...

Answer (score 1):

Several things:
First, Your Threadstatic value creation is better implemented by ThreadLocal. This is basically the case whenever you need your threadstatic field to be initialized. Use

```
private static ThreadStatic<Dictionary<string, string>> headerData = new ThreadStatic<Dictionary<string, string>>(() => new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Second, for acquiring the value from the dictionary, what you're looking for is the TryGetValue method. I.e. not Contains-Get pair (as it does hash lookup twice unnecessary), and certainly not SingleOrDefault.

And third, to have a reliable ID identifying whatever happened from the one service call, just have it as one of the parameters of all the subsequent method calls.